# I want to store void pointers to functions along with the type of them

Tags: c++, function, casting, void-pointers

I am trying to make a vector hold void pointers to functions, which will later be called secuentially.
So, lets say that I have got three functions. `int a()`, `void b();`, `bool c();`

My vector is `vector<void *> vec;`

And my function that stores pointers to functions.

```
void registerFunction(void *func)
{
    vec.push_back(func);
}
```

Now my problem is when trying to call all the functions stored, since they are all void pointers, I just cannot call the functions without knowing their type.

So my question is... is there any way to store types of symbols so I can relate them to their respective pointers and then typecast when calling a void pointer to a function?

**Note**: Functions won’t be always be of type, for example, `void (*)()`, I will want to add methods also, hence ie. `void (someclass::)()`. Is it asking for too much? Should it work?

Comment: "void pointers to functions" - a contradictio in terminis. (you can at the very most get the memory address that corresponds to it, but then you will have left the C++ specs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void*` can't safely be used as a generic pointer-to-function type (though you might be able to get away with it).

But any function-to-pointer value can be converted to another pointer-to-function type and back again without loss of information.  So you can use, for example, `void (*)()` (pointer to function returning void and taking no arguments) as a generic pointer-to-function type.

As for storing the type, I'm not sure that's possible.  If there are only a limited number of possibilities, you can use an enumeration type and a switch statement.

But you'll probably be better off using a design based on inheritance.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot convert a function pointer to `void*`.  It is not allowed.

If all of the functions are callable with zero arguments and you don't care about the return type, you can use `std::vector<std::function<void()>>` (`function` can also be found in Boost and TR1 if your C++ Standard Library does not support it).

Though, if I recall correctly, return-type conversion is not allowed in the C++11 `std::function` implementation, in which case you may need something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct ignore_result_impl
{
    ignore_result_impl(T fp) : fp_(fp) { }
    void operator()() { fp_(); }
    T fp_;
};

template <typename T>
ignore_result_impl<T> ignore_result(T fp)
{
    return ignore_result_impl<T>(fp);
}

int g() { return 42; }
std::function<void()> f(ignore_result(g));
```

(In the Boost implementation I know you can use `function<void()>` directly, but I'm pretty sure that is no longer allowed in C++11.  I could be wrong and I'd appreciate clarification in the comments, if someone does know.)

Comment: I think it's actually allowed (i.e., it's not a constraint violation), but the behavior (not just the result) of the conversion is undefined.  At least that's the case in C; C++ might be different.

Comment: @KeithThompson being undefined is pretty much the same as not being allowed.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I wouldn't say so.  There's a big difference between errors that the implementation is required to diagnose (syntax errors and constraint violations) and errors that it isn't; it's a least important to understand the distinction.  And sometimes code *needs* to be non-portable; such code routinely does things whose behavior is undefined *by the standard*, though it may be defined by something else.  For example, the POSIX `dlsym` function depends on the ability to convert a `void*` to a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all the functions follow the same type signature, you can cast the void pointers back to that type.

A better solution is to typedef the function type:

```
typedef int(*fun_ptr)();
vector<fun_ptr> vec;
```

Then you will not need the cast.

Comment: +1 for the fun_ptr idea. -1 for saying that you can case the pointers back (yes you can cast them; no you cannot claim that you are casting something 'back'; you are casting it to 'something' - undefined)